# Whence construct R.id?

Tags: android

In some code we're trying out, coming from various tutorials, we end up missing *R.id*, which should be generated in *R.java*, obviously. We can add it in (by analogy with other "first" Android projects we've done), but as this file is auto-generated, anything we do like that just gets overwritten ultimately.

```
public static final class id
{
   public static final int Button01=0x7f060004;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Was there a construct to put into *strings.xml*, *main.xml*, etc. that causes this to be generated?

(Yeah, we're total noobs. Sorry.)

Thanks for any help you can give,

Russ Bateman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.java is auto generated by Eclipse. If it is not built, this means you have probably an error somewhere in your xml files, or a resource with a name that is not allowed.
Sometimes it is just Eclipse doing strange things, in this case, you can try :
Project > Clean > all project 
Then let Eclipse work.
Sometimes it solves the issue. If not, it's highly probable that you have an error somewhere in your resources.
To create this file, Eclipse gathers the ids you declared in your xml files with @+id,but also the layout names, images names, string names, ...

Comment: Or, if you're not using Eclipse, it's generated by the aapt tool, usually via Ant.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you, I think we see whence the R.id.whatever is supposed to come now.

Answer (score 2):

Say I have an XML file with the following content:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
 <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I save it in res/layout/ .
Then R.id.ListView01 gets automatically created.

You might want to look at the Notebook Sample application and how it's organised. At least that's how I got familiar with androids organisation.

Comment: Once I had "@+id..." constructs in my main.xml, cleaning (and rebuilding) saw the end of these missing R.id errors. However, my colleague was not so lucky. We'll press on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that *project/res/layout/main.xml* contains the constructs that lead to the generation of *id* in *R.java*. (I'm not limiting the source for these only to that XML file.)

Look specifically for *android:id* in various widgets (I think they're called) such as *TableLayout*, *TextView*, *EditText*, etc. There will be corresponding

```
public static final class id
{
   public static final int x=0x7f05006;
   public static final int y=0x7f05000;
   public static final int z=0x7f0500c;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

where x, y, z correspond to the (*TableLayout*, *TextView*, *EditText*, etc.) identifier coded immediately after the "@+id/" construct in the XML file (and the initialized value in *R.java* is magically generated--you don't have to worry about that).

Thanks to all who contributed.